# Execute command without terminal output

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, command

Let me give a bit of background to my question. I am using a terminal RSS reader `newsboat` which allows for the usage of macros to operate on links. For example, I have a macro running `cd ~/videos && youtube-dl %u`, which will download a youtube video to `~/videos`. However, the output of `youtube-dl` will be printed in my terminal until the download is complete and for this time I cannot continue using `newsboat`.

I am wondering how I could phrase the command so that it is executed “somewhere else” so that I can immediately continue using the terminal from which it is run.

Comment: Why the downvote? I know that applications like `youtube-dl` are off-topic, but I think my question is not.

Comment: Please specify:  Are you asking about discarding output, or are you asking about job control (e. g. running processes in the background)?

Comment: @JohnDorian Here is a +1 to compensate that :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't need the output at all then redirect it to /dev/null

```
yourcommand > /dev/null 2>&1
```

otherwise you can redirect into a file:

```
yourcommand > /somwhere/file 2>&1
```

And as you run the command from another application and you want use your news reader immediately you may want to run the command in the background. I am not sure how it works in this newsboat, but in a shell you can send programs into the backround with &

```
yourcommand > /somwhere/file 2>&1 &
```

Comment: what does 2>&1 mean?

Comment: 2>&1 redirects the stderr (2) to the stdout (1). As the stdout is redirected to a file, it writes the stderr to the same file.

Answer (score 2):

To run command silently in background, which will "survive" even if terminal will be closed afterwards, use `screen` in detached mode:

```
screen -dm your_command(-s)
```

to reattach `screen` with the command running execute

```
screen -r
```

To detach reattached screen press `CTRL+A+D`.

Without `screen` you should execute your command with `nohup`, thus the process will run if the terminal is closed afterwards, like the `screen` utility:

```
nohup your_command(-s) &>/dev/null  &
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question starts asking one thing, but then goes into asking about another thing.

The first thing you ask about is discarding output.  This is easily done with redirection:

```
$ echo hello 1> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The second thing you ask about is running a command "somewhere else" so that you can continue using the terminal.  This is called "Job Control".

You can execute any command in the background using the shell's `&` command separator.  Compare the behavior of the following two commands:

```
$ sleep 5
$ sleep 5 &
```

If a job is already running and you need to use the terminal for other things, and you want the job to complete, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the job and `bg` to tell it to continue in the background:

```
$ (sleep 10; echo hello)
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ( sleep 10; echo hello )
$ bg
[1]+ ( sleep 10; echo hello ) &
$ echo farewell
farewell
$ fg
( sleep 10; echo hello )
hello
```

[This link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) has some fairly good reading about job control with `bash`.

Comment: I think I need both discarding output and background here. (Since I am quite a newbie, I couldn't specify the abstract concepts I was looking for, that's why I gave my concrete context.) Thank you for pointing me to the concept of job control, I will certainly read more on this topic!